# RDC and black screen mystery

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

The following are all Windows 7 64 bit Business edition computers.

I have a PC (lets call it "PC1") that I remotely access now and again using Remote Desktop Connection (RDC) on my laptop downstairs.  Sometimes when I physically go back to sit at PC1, the screen is black and there is no way for me to wake it into life, no login screen or anything - the PC is still on and I am always forced to do a hard reboot.  What can I do to stop this happening, it's really annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue which is similar, see [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/LiveMesh/feedback/details/485253/black-screen-on-remote-windows-7-computer-after-account-is-switched-and-after-using-live-mesh-remote-desktop-to-this-computer-from-another-computer?wa=wsignin1.0) for the workarounds.  And vote the issue up!

Comment: I have this problem too, but the link is now dead (I guess it worked when the answer was first posted). Can anyone supply a working link, or describe what was in the page the link led to?

Comment: Sorry, I can't find the link or remember the issue.  In the future I'll take care to copy the points into the post.

Answer (score 0):

I am late for the party, but:

1. Create a new Virtual Machine on your Hyper-V.
2. Install Windows 7 from a DVD or an ISO file, whatever makes you happy.
3. On the final reboot of the install, you will, of course, get the above mentioned black screen.
4. Reboot the VM, but this time press a key to boot from the Windows 7 DVD (or boot from your ISO) so that you can get into the repair mode (recovery console/DOS prompt).
5. Type `c:` to go to the C (boot) drive of your Windows 7 VM.
6. Type the following command at the recovery console DOS prompt:
   `bootsect.exe /nt60 all /force`
7. Type `exit` and then reboot the machine.

I had the same issue as you did; I found these steps [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/f324ff98-25ba-4732-87a6-1dada4e8b5e4/windows-7-dont-boot-after-install-hyperv?forum=virtualmachingmgrhyperv), and that helped me.